# javascript error logger being passed a retry function that I want to log the details of

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing

I've got a bunch of AJAX calls that might throw an error.  Each of them calls a ShowError(e, f) function I've setup.  The e parameter is the error object, and the f parameter is a function to be called if the user hits try again on the error dialog I show them.  I've got it calling the retry function, but I'd like to log it too.  I can call f.toString() to get the code of the retry function, but I'm looking for the values that code is using and I'm unable to find them.

The original call:

```
function callServer(a,b,c) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/ajax/code/that/might/produce/an/error/',
        data: JSON.stringify({ a: a, b: b, c: c }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        accepts: "application/json",
        success: function (result) {
            alert("good");
        },
        error: function (e) {
            showError(e, function () { callServer(a, b, c); });
        }
    });
}
```

The showError function

```
var reTryFunction;
function showError(e, f) {
    reTryFunction = f;
    $("#hdnJSError").val((JSON.stringify(e)).replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;"));
    $("#ErrorModal").modal("show");
}
```

The retry function called from the user hitting the retry button on the ErrorModal dialog

```
function retry()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/ErrorReport',
        data: JSON.stringify({ txtErrorReport: $("#txtErrorReport").val(), hdnJSError: $("#hdnJSError").val(), reTryFunction: reTryFunction.toString() }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        accepts: "application/json",
        success: function (result)
        { },
        error: function (result)
        {
        }
    });

    $("#txtErrorReport").val("");

    $("#ErrorModal").modal("hide");
    reTryFunction();
}
```

Doing this I can have a generic error handler that shows me that "function(){callServer(a,b,c)}" is what went wrong, but I want to know what the values of a, b, and c were (in a generic way so if the originally calling function had 1 or 9999 parameters passed to it, it still tells my error logger what was passed to it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can saparate out the callback's parameters to separate parameter like so

```
   error: function (e) {
        showError(e, callServer, [a,b,c]);
    }
```

Then in your show error you have access to the params

Even if you don't know how many parameters there are you can make use of the spread operator to pass in the params https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

```
function showError(e, f, params) {
    consolelog(params);
    reTryFunction = function () { f(...params); }
    $("#hdnJSError").val((JSON.stringify(e)).replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;"));
    $("#ErrorModal").modal("show");
}
```

Comment: f(...params)  I've never seen a triple dot operator in code.  Interesting.

Comment: It's a spread operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax
You can also pass in the params directly param[0], param[1], but it sounds like you won't always know how many there are

Comment: ya not knowing how many there are is why I wasn't passing the parameters in the first place, but with this I can still call the function and still log what to pass to it.

Comment: Btw spread operators are not compatible with internet explorer if you need to support that.

Comment: @BrianHeward I edited my answer to bring attention to the spread operator being the solution